# Search for file end with .txt in subdirectories in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, glob

What I want to do is searching for all files that end with .txt in the subdirectories, for example, I am in directory called *user*, which holds only the directories *Test1* and *Test2*. *Test1* contains t1.txt and another subdirectory *Test3*. *Test2* contains t2.txt. *Test3* contains t3.txt

I try to use find and egrep

```
find */ -name "*.txt" | egrep "*/[^/]*(.txt)$"
```

but it gives me

```
Test1/Test3/t3.txt
Test1/t1.txt
Test2/t2.txt
```

I want to print something like

```
Test1/t1.txt
Test2/t2.txt
```

Since I just want files end with .txt in subdirectories (not subdirectories of subdirectories)
What am I supposed to do in order to get the result I want? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just `ls */*.txt`

Comment: Or rather `echo */*.txt` (or maybe `printf` if you have funky file names).

Comment: @tripleee This actually solve the problem. I was over thinking. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want

```
 find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name "*.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. :) but I just want the files in the subdirectories. This will also print files in current directory.

Comment: @OKC No problem, edited answer to add "-mindepth 2"; now it does exactly that!

Answer (score 2):

from `man find`:

```
   -maxdepth levels
      Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of direc-
      tories below the command line arguments.   '-maxdepth  0'  means
      only  apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `awk` or `basename`  or `dirname`

```
  awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: -1 This does not appear to be an answer to this particular question.